# Google Analytics for my Adobe AIR app is not working very well

Tags: android, actionscript-3, google-analytics, air

I've put the Google Analytics code in my AIR app in order to track the name of the page that user are viewing.

So my AS3 code goes like :

```
var gaid = "UA-*******-1";
```

And in the first line of frame 2 :

```
var tracker2:SimplestTracker = new SimplestTracker( gaid );
    tracker2.sendPageview( "/postAnnonce", "Page postAnnonce" );
```

But in my Google Analytics account many problems. 
The page "postAnnonce" is displayed, but it says that 0 user are displaying this screen (so it's wrong as I am displaying it on my device).

Secondly, each time I go to a frame, Google Analytics add an "active user" in the real time information.

Example : I went to frame 2, then 1, then 3, then 1, then 5, then 1, then 4 : it tells me that there is 7 active user in the app (but I launch the app on only 1 device !).

Do you know what is the problem ?

Comment: You need to remove or comment out line 164 (`return _generateUUID();`) within the `SimpleTracker.as` file as it is generating a new client id each time a SimpleTracker object is created. https://github.com/zwetan/as3-universal-analytics/blob/master/src/libraries/uanalytics/SimplestTracker.as#L164  https://github.com/zwetan/as3-universal-analytics/wiki/SimplestTracker